# Angular js 1.0 vs Angular js 2.0

Tags: angularjs, angular

angular1 vs angular2. Does it mean that support for angular1 will not available in future? While developing an application which version should go with angular1 or 2.

Comment: See [angular 1 vs angular 2 for new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229956/angular-1-vs-angular-2-for-new-project/44328165#44328165)

Answer (score 0):

Angular1 and Angular2 are quite different. Angular2 is actually a complete rewrite not an improved Angular2. Between Angular1 and Angular2 there was also Angular.dart which already was a complete rewrite and in retrospect can be seen as a prototype for Angular2. Just to make it obvious how much difference is between Angular1 and Angular2.

I'm sure Angular1 will be supported as long as there is a substantial number of users. Afterwards it's still available as open source and can be maintained by the community.