# angularJS vs angular 2 for new project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am preparing to build an UI for my scala application. I have some very good knowledge about Angular 1 and I know very little about Angular 2.

The question I am asking is whether I should use Angular 2 for my new application instead of Angular 1.

I googled this and read a few articles about things I already knew regarding Angular 2 vs Angular 1 but I am much more interested in the experts opinion regarding this subject. The reason I put the question here is that this subject didn't have any answer in the first two pages. My application is not big at this point and is not going to be that big.

So should I stick with Angular 1 or go for Angular 2? Why?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation to yours and I'm personally going to build my app with Angular 2 as I think it'd be a good idea to learn it.

Comment: this may answer your question, as this is opinion based.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angular-vs-angular-2

Comment: Switch to [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) :)

Comment: You want an expert opinion, and yet you're asking us. heh.

Comment: @KevinB I didn't say expert, I said `very good knowledge`. It is a big difference for me. Regarding version 2, I said I just wrote a few lines.

Comment: *"but I am much more interested in the experts opinion regarding this subject"*

Comment: @MuratOzgul Many resources on the Internet regarding this topic. Why switch to react?

Comment: @tzortzik After trying both, I find React easier to grasp and reason about (I am not an Angular expert, but I now use React and React-Native with Redux everyday at work). I think you should at least complete one tutorial and give it a shot

Comment: Use angularJS2 for personal project or in startup environement, angular will dominate in 5 years, you can start now. But I think it's not reasonnable to use it in a big company in 2016 !

Comment: I am going to start my project in Dec 2016. Should i Use Angular 2 ? Also, how good is the support for Angular 2 ?

Answer (score 14):

We were in the same situation for the brand new project. We decide to stick with Angular 1, because:

1. Fast forward. We have very thin deadlines. We must deliver and we have knowledge how do it with Angular 1.
2. Angular 1 is production ready. Although Angular 2 isn't a problem, but all around Angular 2 it's. ui-router is in alpha, some modules doesn't exists for Angular 2.
3. Overhead. AMD or SystemJS has huge overhead in comparison to oclazyload. We don't have knowledge out-the-box how to strip weight down with Angular 2. We don't have time to figure every aspect for Angular 2.

So, I think, if your poject plan is around 2 years or more - choose Angular 2. For fast forward stick with what you know.

Answer (score 12):

Choose Angular 2 if:

- You have no major deadline to hit, and time to spare to learn the correct Angular 2 practices.
- You enjoy getting a jump start in learning the latest and greatest.
- Your project is small enough to refactor while learning, without too much of a headache.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to start with **Angular 2.x** (Current stable version **version 2.4**).

Angular 2 has improved lot in terms of design and speed. Only it is very different from Angular 1 and will have more learning curve. Angular 2 is released in October 16. So it is more stable now. Angular 4 is released in March 17. Each 6 months, they will be releasing new version. (I read as Angular 5 in Oct 17 and Angular 6 in Mar 18, But not sure about this.)

Reasons to use Angular 2.

1. **Speed** - Angular 2 is 5x to 10x faster than Angular 1
2. **Mobile Support** - It is good to have mobile support. Angular 1 don't have support
3. **Routing** - Routing improved. It is good for SEO.
4. **Testing and Debugging** - This is good in Angular 2 and good while development
5. **Templating** - Templating is good and managed well in Angular 2.
6. **Documentation** - Doc is maintained good and complicated concepts from Angular 1 are no longer exists. Huge community is there to help in Angular 2.
7. **Cost to Upgrade** - Angular 2 is completely rewritten so we can not upgrade from Angular 1 to Angular 2 easily. Project will need to write from scratch if want to upgrade. As most of the concepts are deprecated and rewritten.
8. **New versions** - Angular 2 can be easily upgraded to Angular 4 by some find-replaces and additions. Angular 4 have not much changes than Angular 2. New versions (A5, A6) will not have drastic changes in design than Angular 2 and can be easily upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

if you choose AngularJS you can use with ready-made library for AngularJS which are tried long time and stabilized.Also The github star is quite satisfying and you can easily use it.

If you have got any problem you can solve it very quickly.Because it have been using for a long time , the same problem encountered by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely think you should migrate! The main advantage in my opinion is its boost in performance, since Angular is 5 times faster than Angular JS. Another plus is its mobile-driven approach. Unlike version 1.x, latest versions were designed to create native mobile apps by using strategies from other mobile-oriented frameworks such as Nativescript, Ionic Framework or React Native as well as performance improvements such as lazy loading or AOT compilation. Recently I wrote a Blog Post about this, you can read some more benefits and find out my tips for migrating to Angular here: https://blog.uruit.com/2017/07/04/angular-1-vs-2-migrate/